# Norm Inequalities in Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

Consider $B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times h}$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{h\times n}$. We can make sense of
\begin{align*}
    \lVert BA\rVert_{1,\infty} = \sup_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\lVert x\rVert_1 = 1\}}\lVert BAx\rVert_{\infty}
\end{align*}
and we know
\begin{align*}
      \lVert BA\rVert_{1,\infty} \leq     \lVert B\rVert_{1}\lVert A\rVert_{1,\infty} 
\end{align*}
Now, let $a = \lVert A\rVert_{1,\infty}$ and Consider
\begin{align*}
    BA = (aB)(a^{-1}A)
\end{align*}
Let $k$ be an integer such that $k^{-1}a\lVert B\rVert_1 < 1$ and define $\tilde{B} = k^{-1}aB$ and $\tilde{A} = a^{-1}A$. Then
\begin{align*}
    BA &=(aB)(a^{-1}A)\\
    &=k\tilde{B}\tilde{A}\\
    &=(\tilde{B} + \cdots +\tilde{B})\tilde{A}\\
    &=\begin{bmatrix}
        \tilde{B} & \cdots & \tilde{B}
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        \tilde{A} \\ \vdots \\ \tilde{A}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
    \Big\lVert\begin{bmatrix}
        \tilde{B} & \cdots & \tilde{B}
    \end{bmatrix} \Big\rVert_{1} < 1
\end{align*}
because it it is the maximum column sum of absolute values and this is just the same as that of one $\tilde{B}$ which by construction satisfies $<1$.  Similarly, we have
\begin{align*}
    \Bigg\lVert\begin{bmatrix}
        \tilde{A} \\ \vdots \\\tilde{A}
    \end{bmatrix} \Bigg\rVert_{1,\infty}  &= \sup_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\lVert x\rVert_1 = 1\}}\Bigg\lVert\begin{bmatrix}
        \tilde{A} \\ \vdots \\\tilde{A}
    \end{bmatrix}x \Bigg\rVert_{\infty}\\
    &=\sup_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\lVert x\rVert_1 = 1\}}\Bigg\lVert\begin{bmatrix}
        \tilde{A}x \\ \vdots \\\tilde{A}x
    \end{bmatrix} \Bigg\rVert_{\infty}\\
    &\sup_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\lVert x\rVert_1 = 1\}}\lVert
        \tilde{A}x \rVert_{\infty}\\
        &= \lVert \tilde{A}\rVert_{1,\infty}
\end{align*}
which is $1$ by construction. Then
\begin{align*}
     \lVert BA\rVert_{1,\infty} &=   \Bigg\lVert\begin{bmatrix}
      \tilde{B} & \cdots & \tilde{B}
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        \tilde{A} \\ \vdots \\ \tilde{A}
    \end{bmatrix}\Bigg\rVert_{1,\infty}\\
     &\leq       \Big\lVert\begin{bmatrix}
        \tilde{B} & \cdots & \tilde{B}
    \end{bmatrix} \Big\rVert_{1}  \Bigg\lVert\begin{bmatrix}
        \tilde{A} \\ \vdots \\\tilde{A}
    \end{bmatrix} \Bigg\rVert_{1,\infty}\\
    & < 1
\end{align*}
But this cant be right for arbitrary $A,B$. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: @dezdichado the norm in the input space is the 1-norm not that $\infty$ norm

Comment: ok - according to wikipedia, it seems like you should have:
$$\|BA\|_{\alpha, \gamma}\leq \|B\|_{\beta,\gamma}\|A\|_{\alpha, \beta},$$
which seems different than the one you are using to chain the bounds.

Comment: @dezdichado yeah i think thats it. thanks!